# Difference between "al" and "a el"

Tags: gramática

What is the difference between `al` and `a el`? `Al` and `A el` are the same, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Al* is the contraction of *a el*, the preposition *a* (at/to) and the article *el* (the):

> *Dale esto **a-el** cartero.*
>
> *Dale esto **al** cartero.*
>
> Give this to the mailman.

You must always write *al*, never *a el*, unless you're talking of a proper noun that includes *El*:

> *Vamos a El Salvador.*
>
> Let's go to El Salvador.

*A él* is the preposition *a* and the personal pronoun *él* (him).

> *Dale esto a él.*
>
> Give this to him.

Comment: "The rae now recomends not to write él with diacritic" - Do you have a source for this by any chance? I'd very much like to read about this.

Comment: I apparently got mistaken. They never said such thing.

Comment: Probably worth noting that it used to be common to see *ál* (contraction of *a él* — back in the 1600s and all), but after a while in speech *él* was being fully distinguished and so in writing it was stopped too.