# What is the difference between “el hombre” and “al hombre”?

Tags: gramática, artículos, contracciones

I'm using Rosetta Stone, which is great, but it started off teaching me *“el hombre”* then suddenly switched to *“al hombre”*. I know *al* is a contraction of *a el*, but I can't understand when to use *el* vs *al*; e.g.:

> ***Al*** hombre le gusta jugar el fútbol.

vs

> ***El*** hombre come.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Spanish SE. Indeed, "el hombre"="the man", and "al hombre" is "to the man", because "al" means "to the". You seem to be asking why sometimes there is that "to" required. Check that you should provide some context, and some examples, because we don't know if the text is wrong, or if is a special situation. Maybe a personal direct object? Please, clarify.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Simon. We must have already a lot of previous questions covering this topic. What about questions like [Difference between “al” and “a el”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12124/5481) or [Al vs. El - Uses and differences](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18765/5481)

Comment: OK, thank you. I will read up on intransitive verbs and direct/indirect objects. Examples of context: Al hombre le gusta jugar al futbol. El hombre come.

Comment: In your first example, 'hombre' is the **object** of the verb 'gustar'. When objects are persons, they are preceded with 'a'.

In your second example, 'hombre' is the **subject** of the verb 'comer', and hence does not need 'a'.

[This answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18836/18348) gives more examples of this construction.